# strstr not working within the loop as intended

Tags: c

I am learning C from the head first C and I tried making a small program which searches user input within a 2d array.

But my code isn't working as intended and always return false.

My code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char songs[][50] = {"Meri aashiqui ab tum hi ho",
"Aaja Maahi",
"Tum mere ho",
"Akelapan",
"kangana tera ni"};

void search_tar(char target[]) {
    printf("Searching for %s ",target);
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (strstr(songs[i],target))
        {
            printf("Found the track %s from the keyword",songs[i]);
        }
    }


}

int main()
{
    char target[50];
    printf("Find the song with a keyword: ");
    fgets(target,50,stdin);
    search_tar(target);
    return 0;
}
```

Code from the book:

[Code from book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zznwi.png)

I expect the code to output the results.

Comment: Also, if you print out `target` on failure, you would (hopefully) see the newline in it.  Especially when testing something, it's always a good idea to print diagnostics for error conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`target` has a `'\n'` in it - thus no pattern match with `strstr()`.

After reading the line, lop off that potential `'\n'`.

```
target[strcspn(target,"\n")] = 0;
```